# Best way to pass connection string from openshift to .net core application hosted there

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-3

I have created a net core app and deployed on openshift 3. The applcation use connection string from app setting. I want to be able to pass it from open shift environment so I dont have to store them in the repository. Will environment variables in openshift be suitable for this purpose? If yes how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variable setting in the deployment configuration. This can be entered direct into the deployment configuration, or it can be sourced from a config map or secret.

If needing to supply the setting as part of some configuration file, you could instead use a config map or secret and mount those via the deployment configuration into the container as a file that the application reads.

Comment: thanks @graham for the reply. I am trying this but not able to find out what should be the host name in the connection string? I tried internal ip with port and also tried the postgresql pod name as host. but that did not work.  "DefaultConnection": "Server=<what hould be this>;Port=5432;Database=

Comment: It should be the name of the _Service_ object created. Use that name as a hostname. It is added into an internal DNS and will map to the IP address of the _Service_.